# MPAndroidChart values intersection with legend & removing y value from above the bar

Tags: android, bar-chart, legend, mpandroidchart

How can i solve the problem of the values intersecting with the legend while maintaning the same position for the legend, or is it not possible?

Also how can i remove the value from above the bar
I have tried using

```
         mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);
        mChart.setDrawValuesForWholeStack(false);
```

But they are no good

[image: Values intersecting with the legend]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the space **between the largest value and the top** of the graph:

```
YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
leftAxis.setSpaceTop(40f); // e.g. 40% space
```

What this does is setting the top spacing (in percent of the total axis-range) of the highest value in the chart in comparison to the highest value on the axis.

As for removing the y-values that are drawn by the bars: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ChartData-class

Call `setDrawValues(false)` on your `BarData` or `BarDataSet` object.